# There is an error on flutter when I coded to load data from firebase -The getter 'value' isn't defined for the type 'DatabaseEvent'

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is the code in my app

```
Future<void> _loadTransactions() async {
  final year = currentDate.year.toString();
  final month = currentDate.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0');

  final snapshot = await _databaseReference.child(year).child(month).once();
  final Map<String, dynamic>? data = snapshot.value;

  if (data != null) {
    final List<Transaction> loadedTransactions = [];
    data.forEach((key, value) {
      loadedTransactions.add(Transaction.fromMap(key, value));
    });

    setState(() {
      transactions = loadedTransactions;
    });
  }
}
```

There is an error on flutter when I coded to load data from firebase

> The getter 'value' isn't defined for the type 'DatabaseEvent'

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation for the [`once` property](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/Query/once.html) it returns a `Future<DatabaseEvent>`. So your `snapshot` is actually of [type `DatabaseEvent`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/DatabaseEvent-class.html) and that does **not** have a property `value`, which is what the error message indicates.

Based on that:

```
final event = await _databaseReference.child(year).child(month).once();
final snapshot = event.snapshot;
final Map<String, dynamic>? data = snapshot.value;
```